# Passing Data from Controller to View using Ajax to filter results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor

I'm attempting to filter my results based on a drop down selected value. All the filtering and everything is working, I'm just struggling to get my view to update with the results. I'm leaving out some brackets and other irrelevant code Here is what I have:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{    
     -- this effectively returns all Invoices no matter what date --
     var data = new UserBAL().GetInvoice(date);
     return View(data);                 
}
```

My Jquery and Ajax is :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("[name='DDLItems']").change(function () {
         var selection = $("[name='DDLItems']").val();
         var dataToSend = {
             //variable to hold selection?
             idDate: selection
         };

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "Invoice/FilterInvoice",
             data: dataToSend,
             success: function (data) {   
                $("#Index").html(data);                     
             }
```

```c#
[HttpPost]                     // Selected DDL value 
public ActionResult FilterInvoice(int idDate)
{       
     switch (idDate)
    { 
        case 0:
             date = DateTime.Parse("01-01-1754");
             break;

        case 3:
             date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12);
             break;
     }
     //var data is returning my expected results 
     var data = new UserBAL().GetInvoice(date);

    // I know this isn't right and needs to be changed 
     return View(data);
```

My ajax success function isn't doing anything either So it i'm guessing this needs some tweaking. Also Here's how I am displaying the table using table tags. Keep in mind I left some code out but everything important is here, and the only issue is rendering my filtered results back to the view,

```
  @foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr><td>   
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Invoice_Number)        
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amt_Total)
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer if anyone else comes across this. This is what I ended up doing, the rows are getting filtered passed on the date parameter I'm passing to the URL of the function. Having the Grid populate inside the Ajax call also seemed like it was a problem so I had to take it out.

```
 public JsonResult JqGrid(int idDate)
    {
         switch (idDate)

         #region switch date
            --Switch Statement--
        #endregion
        var invoices = new UserBAL().GetInvoice(date);

        return Json(invoices, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]  // pretty much does nothing, used as a middle man for ajax call 
    public JsonResult JqGridz(int idDate)
    {
        switch (idDate)
        #region switch date

          --Switch Statement--
        #endregion

        var invoices = new UserBAL().GetInvoice(date);

        return Json(invoices, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Yes these two functions seem very redundant and they are. I don't know why my post wouldn't update data, but I needed to reload the grid each time and when I did that it would call the first function. So yea the post jqGridz is kinda of just a middle man.

Here's the jquery code I used

```
var dropdown
var Url = '/Invoice/JqGrid/?idDate=0'  
         $(document).ready(function () {

$("#jqgrid").jqGrid({ 
    url: Url,
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET', //insert data from the data object we created above 
    width: 500,  
    colNames: ['ID','Invoice #', 'Total Amount', 'Amount Due', 'Amount Paid', 'Due Date'], //define column names
    colModel: [
    { name: 'InvoiceID', index: 'Invoice_Number', key: true, hidden: true, width: 50, align: 'left' },
    { name: 'Invoice_Number', index: 'Invoice_Number', width: 50,  align: 'left'},
    { name: 'Amt_Total', index: 'Amt_Total', width: 50, align: 'left' },
    { name: 'Amt_Due', index: 'Amt_Due', width: 50, align: 'left' },
    { name: 'Amt_Paid', index: 'Amt_Paid', width: 50, align: 'left' },
    { name: 'Due_Date', index: 'Due_Date', formatter: "date", formatoptions: { "srcformat": "Y-m-d", newformat: "m/d/Y" }, width: 50, align: 'left' },

    ],                     
    pager: jQuery('#pager'), 
    sortname: 'Invoice_Number',  
    viewrecords: false, 
    editable: true,
    sortorder: "asc",  
    caption: "Invoices",       
});
$("[name='DDLItems']").change(function () {
    var selection = $(this).val();
     dropdown = {
        //holds selected value 
        idDate: selection
    };

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "Invoice/JqGridz",
        data: dropdown,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {         
            $("#jqgrid").setGridParam({ url: Url + selection})               
             $("#jqgrid").trigger('reloadGrid');
        }
    })      

  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing view you can return the partial view as string then in ajax success using jquery you can update the result :

Controller Logic:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult FilterInvoice(int idDate)
{     
 .....  
 return Json((RenderRazorViewToString("YourViewName", data)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}


    [NonAction]
    public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Ajax call :

```
    $.ajax({
    //........
    success: function (result) {
        $("#Index").replaceWith(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: This appears to be working, but now the error message I am getting is: there is no view Data of type ... that has the key "DDLItems" on populating my dropdown list at  @Html.DropDownList("DDLItems") in my view

Comment: I repopulated my dropdown in the NonAction method, it got rid of the error message, but still nothing is happening

Comment: have you debugged the data in ajax success call?

Comment: it says insert row is not defined... if it helps i am using a table inside a for each statement to display results

Comment: I tried that before, still nothing, I'm not sure what the problem. I think it's because I am not replacing my table with my foreach loop correctly. I did something similiar earlier, and my success function looked like  $('label[for=myLabel]').html(data.agent) which was just populating a label, I'm not sure what needs to be done for a table

Comment: I've also noticed that my success function is returning false

Comment: My success is returning false b/c I'm using a "Combo View Model" so I'm populating 1 model with data while the other model is null, so now I don't know where to turn, unless I put my logic in the on false of the method but that seems like cheating